# How can i call all tests methods using testng inside a class where testId's from excel is equal to tests methods

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-eclipse

This is sample sample code trying to fetch all test Id's from excel and I need to execute corresponding test methods where `testid = testmethod`

[image]

Comment: Implement the IMethodInterceptor listener - You can filter the tests you need to run. I am not sure but it might not work with test methds which are in a dependency chain with other test methods. Refer this -
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824620/whats-the-differences-between-iinvokedmethodlistener-and-imethodinterceptor-in-t

Comment: Could you share `TestIDAmcLogin01` and explain how you want to run the test?

Comment: Thank u Grasshopper..

Comment: @juherr i got what i was trying to do..Thanks u